# Examples of JPA joins on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

Are there any good examples for using JPA joins using Google App engine? I saw an example on [this](http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2010/03/executing-simple-joins-across-owned.html) site, but it seems old - are there any improvements on it? The GAE doc pages only detail joins using the low-level API.

Comment: JPA is JPA. A JPA join on GAE is not different from a JPA join on a RDBMS. Beware that on GAE, *you cannot use a field of a child entity in a filter when performing a query on the parent kind*, though.

Comment: I know JPA is JPA , but there are do's and do nots, as you said. I'd appreciate some examples of those as well.

Comment: @JB, another thing is that I tried the simple JPA joins and they just didn't work... So I'm looking for some examples for something that _does_..

Answer (score 2):

Why not look at the tests for GAE/J JPA plugin ?
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus

Answer (score 0):

There is a link on this page that might help you. http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/how-to-do-joins-in-appengine/